# Why is image not centering if text is too long? (using display: table; margin: 0 auto; to horizontally center)

Tags: html, css

### Problem

**What is happening**
[image]

**What should happen**
[image]

For some reason, if the caption is too long it causes the image and the header text below it to shift to the far left. How can I fix this?

If someone could provide me the css to horizontally center the `img`, `h3`, and `h4` that would be greatly appreciated!

### Code

*html*

```
<div class="form-screen form-photo">
    <button class="close close-form"><span class="icon-x"></span></button>
      <div class="form-wrapper">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <h2>Date created</h2>
        <img src="images/Beauty Gurus/Karen Yeung.jpg" alt="Karen Yeung" id="2">
       <!--if the caption is too long the image does not center-->
        <h3>EDIT: VIDEO IS LIVE!!!! Ok Night ? Owls Or Early ? Birds?! Are You Awake? My Jet Lag Is Screwing My Up And I</h3>
        <h4>Credit</h4>
      </div>
</div>
```

*css*

```
/*Style form photo*/
.form-photo .form-wrapper{
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.form-photo h3, .form-photo h4{
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.form-photo h2{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form-photo h3{
  font-size: 2em;
}

.form-photo h4{
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.form-photo img{
  width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need the `display:table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to restrict the width of the text to match the width of the image, or you can just restrict the width of the parent, and set the image to `width: 100%`.

```css
.form-photo .form-wrapper{
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.form-photo h3, .form-photo h4{
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.form-photo h2{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form-photo h3{
  font-size: 2em;
}

.form-photo h4{
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.form-photo {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-screen form-photo">
    <button class="close close-form"><span class="icon-x"></span></button>
      <div class="form-wrapper">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <h2>Date created</h2>
        <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="Karen Yeung" id="2">
        <h3>EDIT: VIDEO IS LIVE!!!! Ok Night ? Owls Or Early ? Birds?! Are You Awake? My Jet Lag Is Screwing My Up And I</h3>
        <h4>Credit</h4>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, `margin: 0 auto` does work with an auto width, but the auto width takes precedence over the auto margins, and the auto margins are zeroed out as a result, making it seem as though they "don't work".

So you need to specify width to the element.

```css
/*Style form photo*/

body {
  width: 100%;
}

.form-photo .form-wrapper {
  width: 40%; /*Added width*/
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form-photo h3,
.form-photo h4 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.form-photo h2 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form-photo h3 {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.form-photo h4 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.form-photo img {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-screen form-photo">
  <button class="close close-form"><span class="icon-x"></span></button>
  <div class="form-wrapper">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h2>Date created</h2>
    <img src="images/Beauty Gurus/Karen Yeung.jpg" alt="Karen Yeung" id="2">
    <!--if the caption is too long the image does not center-->
    <h3>EDIT: VIDEO IS LIVE!!!! Ok Night ? Owls Or Early ? Birds?! Are You Awake? My Jet Lag Is Screwing My Up And I</h3>
    <h4>Credit</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To center an image, use margin:0 auto; and make it into a block element: `display:block;` css property. Not using `display:table;`